# Array Out Of Bounds, Args Issue

Tags: java, arrays

So when I compile, everything will compile just fine.

When I go to run the program, I get this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at ClientForNoDupCollection.main(ClientForNoDupCollection.java:20)

I go to look at line 20(actually 19-21)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    Scanner cReader = null;
```

I'm attempting to be able to do command line execution of the files.

I'm not 100% sure where I went wrong there.

Comment: come on, there was the same question 10 minutes ago

Answer (score 7):

You have not provided any [command-line arguments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) to your application. Thus, `args` has no element 0.

Provide an argument (the path to the file of interest) when invoking your application:

```
java MyApp path/to/file
```

Comment: I go to the terminal window, I use java (javafilename) (txt) file all in the same directory.

Comment: java ClientForNoDupCollection testdata.txt

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a parameter when you run the application.